# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to strTypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str in a chatbot in python

Tags: python, project, chatbot

I'm trying to do a chat bot with python only but I have a problem with the main function that calls for the bot response, an exception occurs when calling it.

Here is the whole code

```py
import re

import long_response as long

def message_probability(user_message, recognised_words, single_response=False, required_words=[]):
    message_certainty = 0
    has_required_words = True

    for word in user_message:
        if word in recognised_words:
            message_certainty += 1
    # Counts how many words are present in each predefined message
    percentage = float(message_certainty) / float(len(recognised_words))

    for word in required_words:
        if word not in user_message:
            has_required_words = False
            break

    if has_required_words or single_response:
        return int(percentage*100)
    else:
        return 0

def check_all_messages(message):
    highest_prob_list = {}

    def response(bot_response, list_of_words, single_response=False, required_words=[]):
           nonlocal highest_prob_list
           highest_prob_list[bot_response] = message_probability(message, list_of_words, single_response, required_words)

           #Responses------------------------------------------------------
           response('Hello !' , ['hello', 'hi', 'sup', 'hey', 'yo', 'heyo', 'hello there'], single_response=True)
           response('I\'m great, doing just fine,and you ?', ['how', 'are', 'you', 'doing'], required_words=['how'])
           response('Oh...Thanks...I guess.I\'m a chatbot so I\'m not used to such kindess', ['i', 'love', 'code', 'palace'], required_words=['code', 'palace'])
           response('You are welcome, that\'s my purpose after all.', ['thank', 'you'], required_words=['thank', 'thanks'])

           best_match = max(highest_prob_list, key=highest_prob_list.get)
           print(highest_prob_list)

           return best_match

def get_response (user_input):
    split_message = re.split(r'\s+|[,;?!.-]\s*' , user_input.lower())
    response = check_all_messages(split_message)
    return response

# Testing response system
while True :
    print('Bot:' + get_response(input('You: ')))
```

I was expecting an appropriate response from the bot, but I got this:

```
File "C:\Users\ivann\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 51, in <module>
    print('Bot:' + get_response(input('You: ')))
          ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

Comment: What is your question about this error?

Comment: This error tells you that `get_response(input('You: '))` is `None`. Please provide a [mre] which includes `get_response()`, or at least provide us the value passed to `input()`.

Comment: `get_response` returns the result of `check_all_messages`, and that function doesn’t return anything, because it doesn’t do anything.

Answer (score -1):

When coding in Python (and some other languages), it's usually best to avoid concatenating strings. Here's an example:

```py
x = 12

# bad
print("x has value " + str(x))

# very bad; raises an exception unless x is a string
print("x has value " + x)

# good
print("x has value", x)

# also good
print(f"x has value {x}")
```

You're running into an error because `get_response()` returned the value `None`, and Python doesn't know how to combine `None` with a string using the `+` operator.

Comment: While generally correct, this would just sweep the error under the rug. The problem is that the function returns `None`, which is incorrect. The function needs to be fixed; then it won’t matter how the string is being concatenated.